# Is there a way to retrieve the JWT token specific to a AAD account user(current logged in user Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement)?

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-365, jwt

We are looking for a way to retrieve the JWT token specific to the current logged in user of Dynamics 365 CE. This is required for one of our integration to pass the JWT to the legacy system using APIM & logic app a middle layer. Below is the entire flow of the integration for which we need this.

1. CE user will call APIM url(which masks the logic app of http trigger) using some action in the form.
2. I have enabled the oauth2.0 in the APIM settings and enabled the validate jwt policy.
3. In CE JavaScript code while calling the APIM URL , we are sending the jwt (that we received using the client id & secret configured in our AAD). This is authenticating the validate jwt policy and oauth 2.0 setting.
4. The same jwt token we need to pass to the logic app and subsequently to the legacy API using an HTTP action.

Now, we are looking for a way to send the jwt token of the logged in user in CE to the APIM url rather than the one generated using the client id & secret.

Please let us know if this is achievable or we need to change our design.

The whole discussion with customer started about securing the data access in the legacy system. If we use the client id & secret jwt, it is tied to one permanent service account(with system admin role) in CE.

We want to avoid that and retrieve the data from legacy system to which the CE logged user might have access to as per the AAD permission & roles. Please give your suggestions here.

Comment: How do you authenticate the user in D365 CE? Do you use some D365 SDK? Have you looked at D365 docs about this? And please tell me you do not use client credentials flow in JS! It seems the question is more D365 CE then anything else.

Comment: Hi astaykov , Thanks for the quick response. i am more keenly looking at how we can generate the claims of the specific user. the client can be anything. right now i am using the postman as a client to generate the JWT using the client id/secret.

i am looking for something like below to be generated for a specific user. 

    "name": "Sathya Karimela",
    "oid": "...",
    "platf": "3",
    "scp": "user_impersonation",
    "sub": "...",
    "tid": "...",
    "unique_name": "sathya@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    "upn": "sathya@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",